# Why would one declare undefined with “var undefined;” before checking against it?

Tags: javascript, undefined

I was looking at this question: [Check if an object is defined: best practice](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3954630/check-if-a-object-is-defined-best-practice) and noticed an answer with something I haven’t seen before:

```
function isDefined(x) {
    var undefined;
    return x !== undefined;
}
```

What would be the reason to declare `undefined` and leave it not defined — in other words define `undefined` as `undefined`?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Some people are convinced that using `undefined` directly is bad because someone could do `window.undefined = "whatever"`. This is because, in ES5 and before (we'll see what comes later), `undefined` is *not* a reserved word and can be used as an identifier.

The local `var` prevents such a bad global variable poisoning - it introduces a local variable called "undefined" (which will shadow any bad variable that may exist) who's value defaults to the real undefined value because there is no assignment.

If I was so concerned (which I am not), I would do `x !== (void 0)`. Unlike `undefined`, [the `void` operator](http://es5.github.io/#x11.4.2) has always been a reserved word and so it is immune to aforementioned poisoning.

Comment: Awesome answer with an explanation of a simpler alternative, Thanks! Give me 7 minutes and I'll make it as accepted.

Comment: `typeof foo !== 'undefined'` is another option.

Comment: @Matt Indeed another idiom that is used a good bit. I *usually* just do `foo !== undefined` if I need such strict check as I find it simpler and it avoids the urge to allow "undeclared variables". In any environment for which `undefined === void 0` is not true, I wave my hands and walk away as additional (valid) assumptions may also be invalidated.